# Adb not detecting my sony xperia J

Tags: adb, sony-xperia

I am trying to debug my android application in sony xperia J but the

```
adb devices 
returns no devices
```

I have enabled USB debugging, Mass storage and installed sony pc companion.
I also allowed to install external applications.
I tried with enabling USB teathering.
Is there any additional setting I am missing?

I guess I have installed drivers for it but I am not very sure.
Can somebody help me on this it is really irritating.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is should be in http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you are using window OS then check this link for device drivers installed or not? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948187

Comment: Try http://moborobo.com/. It helped me to get many devices get visible by ADB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be sure about drivers installed or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply : How can I verify it?

Comment: Hi Got the solution, the usb driver for windows was not insatalled

Answer (score 0):

in my job I see many devices that are not recognised by adb at first.

I have noticed that this is happening due to an auto-mount of the sdcard on the computer.

make sure there are no mounted drives on your computer and that should fix this

Answer (score 0):

You can use PC companion software connect Phone to PC for debugging

Link: http://www.sonymobile.com/in/tools/pc-companion/

and also try it

Settings > Xperia > USB Connectivity > USB Connection Mode and select MASS Storage, not MTP

Answer (score 0):

If your USC pc connection is to **Media device** try changing it to **Camera (PTP)** or Vice Versa.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to configure your phone not to install PC companion when connecting to PC by deselecting it from the phone menu. Also enable USB debugging and Mass storage, then connect the phone to the PC. Delete all devices that look like your phone in the Device Manager by uninstallling them. Then right-click and scan for hardware changes. Go to Android, right-click and Update driver. Browse folder until sdk/extras/google/usbdriver. Then Let me pick... Select Android phone, then have disk browse until sdk/extras/usbdriver. Select android_winusb.inf. Open, then select Android Composite ADB Interface. Next install. Wait until it is done and reopen Eclipse. You will find your phone there under devices.

Answer (score 0):

I am running W8.1 x64 Pro and all above solutions had failed because Windows would not recognize a driver inside of sdk/extras/google/usbdriver even with a manual install.

Anyhow, my solution was to use **Sony's PC companion tool**, which was able to automatically download the drivers for my PC.

Official doc: http://dl-developer.sonymobile.com/documentation/other/Get_drivers_through_PC_Companion.txt

Now the abd interface is installed, and the phone is detected in *adb devices*.